# how do I add additional admin users for gcp console access for a gcp project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a GCP project for a client of mine.  I need the ability to give my client access to the GCP Console for the project.  For example, if my client is traveling and he wants to access his database via MySQL Workbench then he'll need to update the SQL Connections Public IP list with the public ip address for whatever wifi network he's currently connected to.  He could contact me to do that for him, but I would rather give him the ability to do this independently, since I'll eventually be turning the system over to him anyway.

So how can I add my client to my GCP account?  Essentially, I want my client to be able to log into GCP and see everything that I see when I log into GCP as the owner of the account.  I don't want to give my client my GCP login credentials since I may need to create other GCP projects for other clients with those credentials.

Answer (score 1):

For being connected on GCP, your customer need to have a Google account (GMail, GSuite, or something else compliant).

If it hadn't, it can create an account for free in seconds, or it can reuse an existing not Google email to create an account with this email as login and the password of his choice:

- Go to https://accounts.google.com/
- Select create account
- Select `Use my current email address instead`

Then, as narayansharma said, go to IAM page and add this email to your project. I **absolutely** don't recommend you to grant to your customer the `owner` role, because he will be able to do all (create big VM, open any firewall rules, delete resources,...), but select only the roles that you want to grant to him. *If you aren't sure, ask here what is the correct role for your customer usage, and we will be able to help you*

***Note***: *For a connection to Cloud SQL, instead of allowing external IP to reach your database, I recommend you to use [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy).*

Answer (score 0):

You can easily give permission to your client via IAM.
Please follow the given instructions.

- Go to IAM `https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam` and check with your project is correct or not.
- Click on the add button from the page. It will open a pop-up, enter your client email address on the new member field.
- Select project owner roles from roles field.
- Click on save

After save your client can access your project via his personal email.

I hope it will help you.